# VBA big task extracting data from different columns from two different workbooks into two columns in a new workbook

Tags: excel, vba, stack

So I have this task
I have to create a database out of two different files
one have discription column and value columns  and one have the mapping element for this values
I need by using VBA code to
1- MAP Each value to its Element (Vlookup by description)
2- in the Database i stack the above data into two columns only Element and Value
For example First Workbook Has a sheet that contains
Description : Value 1 : Value 2 : Value 3

Secound workbook Has a sheet that contains
Description : Element 1 : Element 2 : Element 3

So
Element 1 : Value 1 : Element 2 : Value 2 : Element 3 : Value 3

The Data Base should look like
|Element |Value |
|:-------|-----:|
|Element1|Value1|
|Element2|Value2|
|Element3|Value3|

I had this code the copy part is working fine , but I got an error in the Vlookup function

```
Sub Copy_Paste_Below_Last_Cell()
'Find the last used row in both sheets and copy and paste data below     existing data.
'Sub OpenWorkbook()

Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim wsMapp As Worksheet

Dim lCopyLastRow As Long
Dim lDestLastRow As Long
Dim lLookupLastRow As Long

  'Set variables for copy , vlookup and destination sheets
  Set wsCopy = Workbooks("A1. Syndicate 623 QMA_20190930_5_0623 with  old version table.xlsx").Worksheets("360")
  Set wsDest = Workbooks("Reports.xlsm").Worksheets("Old")
  Set wsMapp = Workbooks("QMA new format mapping to    old.xlsx").Worksheets("360")


  '1. Find last used row in the copy range based on data in column D
  lCopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

  '2. Find first blank row in the destination range based on data in column J
  'Offset property moves down 1 row
  lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

  '3. Copy & Paste Data
    wsCopy.Range("D15:D" & lCopyLastRow).Copy
    wsDest.Range("J" & lDestLastRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

'vlookup
   '1. Find Last used row in the lookup range based on Data in Column B
lLookupLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    '2. Select Vlookup Start Row
    lLookupLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count,   "I").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

    '3. Vlookup

    Dim Table1 As Range
    Dim Table2 As Range
    Dim cl As Range

    Set Table1 = wsCopy.Range("B15:B" & lLookupLastRow)
    Set Table2 = wsMapp.Range("C15:D37")

    For Each cl In Table1
     wsDest.Range("I" & lLookupLastRow) =   Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(cl, Table2, 2, False)
     Next cl
 
     MsgBox "Done"


  'Optional - Select the destination sheet
  wsDest.Activate

  'Sub CloseWorkbook()

    End Sub
```

'''

Comment: Curious why doing this with VBA?  Seems like a relatively simple copy-paste from worksheet 1, write a VLookup to worksheet 2, and fill it down.

Comment: I am talking about 100 thousands of rows and 100s of files each file has 20 sheets all need to be converted to a database format table.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub lookup()
 Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
 Dim wsDest As Worksheet
 Dim wsMapp As Worksheet

 Dim lLookupLastRow As Long
 Dim lLookupRangeLastRow As Long
 Dim Table1 As Range
 Dim Table2 As Range
 Dim cl As Range

 Set wsCopy = Workbooks("A1. Syndicate 623 QMA_20190930_5_0623 with old version table.xlsx").Worksheets("360")
 Set wsDest = Workbooks("Reports1.xlsm").Worksheets("Old")
 Set wsMapp = Workbooks("QMA new format mapping to old.xlsx").Worksheets("360")
'VLookup
    '1. Find Last used row in the lookup range based on Data in Column B
    lLookupRangeLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

    '2. Select Vlookup Start Row
    lLookupLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

    '3. Vlookup



      Set Table1 = wsCopy.Range("C15:C" & lLookupRangeLastRow)
      Set Table2 = wsMapp.Range("C15:D38")

      For Each cl In Table1
         wsDest.Range("I" & lLookupLastRow) = Application.VLookup(cl, Table2, 2, False)
         lLookupLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
 
      Next cl
 
     MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```